# Color list not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, axis

When I try to color the `addplot` using `cycle list name=color list` it doesn't work for some reason, the color of all the lines stays black. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{scaled y ticks=false}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[xlabel={Dan},ylabel={Promjena vrijednosti (\%)},
yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{100*\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,\%,
ylabel style={align=center,text width=5cm},
xticklabel style={font=\small,/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=2},
yticklabel style={font=\small},
cycle list name=color list]
\addplot[line width=0.2mm] table[x=D,y=R]{C:/Users/User/Desktop/maturski/podaciAnalize/brownianMotion/0.dat};
\addplot[line width=0.2mm] table[x=D,y=R]{C:/Users/User/Desktop/maturski/podaciAnalize/brownianMotion/1.dat};
\addplot[line width=0.2mm] table[x=D,y=R]{C:/Users/User/Desktop/maturski/podaciAnalize/brownianMotion/2.dat};
\addplot[line width=0.2mm] table[x=D,y=R]{C:/Users/User/Desktop/maturski/podaciAnalize/brownianMotion/3.dat};
\addplot[line width=0.2mm] table[x=D,y=R]{C:/Users/User/Desktop/maturski/podaciAnalize/brownianMotion/4.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is example file `0.dat`:

```
R   D
0   0
0.00365519  1
-0.0167845  2
0.010772    3
0.00556351  4
0.0112872   5
-0.00457628 6
0.00495608  7
0.0135412   8
0.00103665  9
0.00274946  10
-0.00198433 11
0.0170662   12
-0.00503909 13
0.0172626   14
-0.00211349 15
0.00543873  16
0.00678182  17
-0.00100652 18
0.000851647 19
-0.00184836 20
-0.00664038 21
0.00061449  22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `cycle list name` to work, you have to use `\addplot+` instead of `\addplot`.

From the `pgfplots` manual (revision  1.18.1, chapter 4.7.7):

> `/pgfplots/cycle list name={name}`
> Allows to specify a list of plot specifications which will be used for each `\addplot` command without
> explicit plot specification. Thus, the currently active cycle list will be used if you write either
> `\addplot+[keys] ...;` or if you don’t use square brackets as in `\addplot[explicit plot specification] ...;`.

For example:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{0.dat}
R   D
0   0
0.00365519  1
-0.0167845  2
0.010772    3
0.00556351  4
0.0112872   5
-0.00457628 6
0.00495608  7
0.0135412   8
0.00103665  9
0.00274946  10
-0.00198433 11
0.0170662   12
-0.00503909 13
0.0172626   14
-0.00211349 15
0.00543873  16
0.00678182  17
-0.00100652 18
0.000851647 19
-0.00184836 20
-0.00664038 21
0.00061449  22
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{scaled y ticks=false}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[xlabel={Dan},ylabel={Promjena vrijednosti (\%)},
yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{100*\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,\%,
ylabel style={align=center,text width=5cm},
xticklabel style={font=\small,/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=2},
yticklabel style={font=\small},
cycle list name=color list]
\addplot+[line width=0.2mm] table[x=D,y=R]{0.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]